# ObjectId to unique shorter string

Tags: c#, mongodb, function, objectid

Since auto generated, incremented Id is not the common way to storing document Ids, I would like to build a function which translates this long ObjectId into a 5-7 long char string.

I would like to acomplish almost the same thing as YouTube does with it's videos whereas every url is really short and they still got billions of them.

Since YouTube's video identifier is 10 chars long, I assume I won't have more than 10m-20m ids, therefore I assume I need much less chars.

Important, I don't need url minimizer, I need it to a different use.
Is there any known algorithm which solves this issue?

Thanks.

What I thought?
Im thinking about taking the `Increment` field from ObjectId and manipulate it, but Im still looking if thats thread safe enough across multiple servers and what happens if it reaches max Int, if its possible.

Also, the `increment` repeats itself once in a while, so taking it is completely just as random number generator.

**Any other needed information would be provided, if relevant**

Comment: You want to convert it to human readable string, right? Not just any arbitrary 5-7 chars?

Comment: Ah, yeah. its not far fetched that people will have to write it by hand.

Comment: ObjectId is 12 bytes, so you cannot convert it to 5-7 human readable characters

Comment: you are right, but, under the assumption that i wont have more than 10m-20m entries it might be.

Comment: @Evk especially when 3 bytes of the objectId are random.

Comment: But for that you need to store the mapping between your short string and real objectid somewhere (in database), you cannot deduce your objectid back from the string itself. And that is essentially "url minimizer" approach. You can for example not use 3 bytes of machine identifier from ObjectId (assuming all your object ids are generated always on the same machine), but that still leaves you with 9 bytes.

Comment: I dont mind storing that value in the database which means I wont be needing the parsing backwards method.
What i mean, the mapping shouldn't  necessarily be a Bijection, it can be Injective function

Comment: Ok I see now what you need. Since you don't mind storing value in database, why not use sequential ids (0,1,2,3 etc) (id of row in database where real ObjectId is stored) and convert them to strings ("aaaaa", "aaaab" and so on)? IF you don't like sequential strings (like above), there are ways to overcome that.

Comment: I couldn't find auto incremented Id option when inserting documents.

Comment: If we are talking about mongodb, you can do it like that: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: It is possible to do that, thanks for letting me know.
Question is, is it possible to avoid maitaining another collection which only serves as 'Id generator'. im really sorry for being too petty

Comment: @Evk either way, it seems like im gonna use this for now. post as answer. ill accept. you may announce that i went full retard on this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't need to use ObjectId at all if you don't like it. Autoincremented id is just fine in certain scenarios. Main reason why people argue against that is because you often use MongoDB in a distributed way, where your tables are located in separate databases on multiple servers, but each document id should be unique among all those databases. But

1. Sometimes you are not planning to do that (sharding) at all, so you don't care about uniqueness problem
2. You can use some service (of your own) to generate sequential unique id. Yes that has some perfomance considerations, but that might be not a problem in *your* particular case.
3. You can split your id sequence yourself. For example, you expect at most 20 million items. So first shard will use sequence 0-20m for id field. Second shard will use 20m-40m (so, start with id = 20.000.000) and so on. That way you might cover all your future requirements for sharding (if you have any at all).

Comment: By the way, If you will need a code to convert interger to readable ascii string - I have some.